# haw to send traffic from vpn to http server

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

hello i have a vpn site to site  i need  configure http porxy  to  wheen 
 wheen client A send traffic to  B with vpn  server B send this request to other API and server B send the result to client .

Client A =====>VPN=====>ServerB====WAN===== ( Server has this is in the WAN API) 
.  i would server B connect to our api and send the answer to client  A

i try with nginx but client A can't reslov the api server 
it's my configuration 
location /api/v1/ {
                 proxy_redirect  http://api.XX/ /api/v1/;
                 proxy_pass http://api.XXX.com/;
                  #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

thank is advance